# Limit question regarding logarthmic function.

Tags: limits

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0}}f(x)$

where $f(x)$=$\frac{\ln(1+x^2+x)+\ln(1+x^2-x)}{secx-cosx}$

What I found was the two ways

Way 1

$L$=$\frac{\frac{\ln(1+x^2+x)(x+x^2)}{(x+x^2)}+\frac{\ln(1+x^2-x)(x^2-x)}{(x^2-x)}}{secx-cosx}$

$L$=$\frac{2x^2}{secx-cosx}$$=$$2$

Way2-

$\frac{\ln(1+x^2+x)+\ln(1+x^2-x)}{secx-cosx}$

$L$=$\frac{\ln((1+x^2+x^4)}{secx-cosx}$

$L$=$\frac{(x^2+x^4)}{secx-cosx}$=1

Which method is correct and why?

Comment: What is the point of introducing $f$ and now use it later?

Comment: @jjagmath I am new to latex so please bear with me

Comment: The first got to an incorrect value. One mistake in it is replacing "equivalents" in a sum. Namely, replacing $\log(1+x^2+x)/(x^2+x)$ with $1$. When that is done in a multiplication, what is being applied is that $\lim(ab)=(lim a)(\lim b)$. This works in the last step of the second method. In the sum, this would be fine, if the order $1$ terms did not cancel. But they do in this case and the information about the order $2$ terms was not preserved. In method 2 I don't know what happened in the first step. The result is correct, but that could be a coincidence.

Comment: @NDB In the second method i used loga+logb=log(ab)

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: @NDB Is it then correct to separately take limits by breaking the fraction into 2

Comment: It depends on what exactly are you calling "breaking the fraction into 2".

Comment: @NDB for example $\frac{a+b}{b}$= $\frac{a}{b}$+$1$

Comment: @TheCuriousOne, the correct result of the limit is $1$, not $2$.

Comment: Please precede the trig functions' names with a backslach. This makes them symbols for LaTeX/MathJax so they are rendered in an upright font with appropriate spacing as function names, not as an amorphous blob of italic (variable-like) letters. See, for example, the results of using `cos x` → $cos x$ versus `\cos x` → $\cos x.$

Answer (score 3):

You could use the notable limits :

$\lim\limits_{t\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+t)}t=1\;\,,\quad$ $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

Now, we will calculate your limit by using  $\,(*)\,$:

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x\right)+\ln\left(1+x^2-x\right)}{\sec x-\cos x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left[\left(1+x^2+x\right)\left(1+x^2-x\right)\right]}{\sec x-\cos x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\big[\left(1+x^2\right)^2-x^2\big]}{\sec x-\cos x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{\sec x-\cos x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{\frac1{\cos x}-\cos x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)\!\cdot\!\cos x}{1-\cos^2\!x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)\!\cdot\!\cos x}{\sin^2\!x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left[\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{x^2\left(1+x^2\right)\cos x}{\sin^2\!x}\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}\!\cdot\!\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\!\dfrac x{\sin x}\!\right)^2\!\!\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0}\big[\!\left(1+x^2\right)\cos x\big]=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}\!\cdot\!1^2\!\cdot\!1=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}\,.$

By letting $\;t=x^2+x^4\,,\;$ it follows that $\;t\to0\;$ as $\;x\to0\;$ and consequently we get that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+t)}t=1\,.$

---

**Addendum :**

It is wrong to calculate your limit in the following way :

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\left(x^2+x\right)\frac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x\right)}{x^2+x}+\left(x^2-x\right)\frac{\ln\left(1+x^2-x\right)}{x^2-x}}{\sec x-\cos x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\left(x^2+x\right)\!\cdot\!1+\left(x^2-x\right)\!\cdot\!1}{\sec x-\cos x}=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\left(x^2+x\right)+\left(x^2-x\right)}{\sec x-\cos x}\,.$

It is wrong because you have calculated the limit of just a part of the function without using any theorem about the calculation of limits.

I have calculated the limit of a part of the function too when I wrote that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left[\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{x^2\left(1+x^2\right)\cos x}{\sin^2\!x}\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}\!\cdot\!\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\!\dfrac x{\sin x}\!\right)^2\!\!\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to0}\big[\!\left(1+x^2\right)\cos x\big]=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}\!\cdot\!1^2\!\cdot\!1=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)}{x^2+x^4}\,,$

but what I did is correct because I applied the theorem that states that the limit of a product is equal to the product of the limits (unless there is the indeterminate form $0\!\cdot\!\infty$).

But which theorem have you applied in your method that you called “way 1” ?

Comment: Please note I have already done this method but please comment about thias method:-$L$=$\frac{\frac{\ln(1+x^2+x)(x+x^2)}{(x+x^2)}+\frac{\ln(1+x^2-x)(x^2-x)}{(x^2-x)}}{secx-cosx}$

$L$=$\frac{2x^2}{secx-cosx}$$=$$2$

Comment: @TheCuriousOne, that method is wrong because you calculate just a part of the function and then you copy the remaining part. In that way you are not applying any theorem about the calculation of the limits.

Comment: what is the difference between what I did and you? Do the function's limits separately converge on their own?

Comment: @TheCuriousOne, read the addendum in my answer and you will know what is the difference.

Comment: Your method 1 error is sort of like saying $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^3-1}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1^2 \cdot x - 1}{x-1} = 1$$

Comment: @aschepler, you are absolutely right !

Comment: @aschepler: +1 for your comment. It is a very simple example which explains the problem with the first approach of asker.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's formula,
$$\log(1+x^2+x)+\log(1+x^2-x)=\log(1+x^2+x^4)=x^2+O(x^4)$$
and
$$\sec x=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4) \\
\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)$$
all as $x\to 0$, hence,
$$\frac{\log(1+x^2+x)+\log(1+x^2-x)}{\sec x-\cos x}=\frac{x^2+O(x^4)}{x^2+O(x^4)}$$
as $x\to0$. The limit is $1$.